# git command for Program FIles (x86)

Tags: git

How to write command in git bash for `Program Files (x86)`? It is giving me error below

```
user@PC /C
$ ./git-credential-winstore -i C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\
sh.exe": syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Can anyone tell me how to write the path for this?

Comment: I think you may have to quote your file path. e.g. `./git-credential-winstore -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\"`

Comment: okay with quote it is not giving an error but than showing `>` on the next line but seems is nothing happening. No idea either it is installing the software or not

Comment: try: ./git-credential-winstore -i "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/"

Comment: How about removing the last \ ? e.g. `./git-credential-winstore -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"`

Comment: @JurisMalinens It's giving message `No such file or directory`

Comment: @Dale this also giving the same message.. No such file or directory

Comment: How about `./git-credential-winstore -i "/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin"`?

Comment: @Dale the same No such file or directory.. Just for your reference her is the actual path on my machine `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`

Comment: Try this `./git-credential-winstore -i /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git/bin`

Comment: try git on a linux machine :p

Comment: @Mali But I don't have Linux installed here.

Comment: @Dale just wonder why this not working.. the last code also doesn't work.. strange..

Comment: Judging by the [git-credential-winstore documentation] (http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/), the argument given to `-i` should be the path to the Git executable, not its directory. That page also states that you don't need the `-i` option if Git is in your path. Since you'll want to have Git in your path anyway you might as well make sure that's the case and drop `-i`.

Comment: You mean the .exe file.. I also thought and checked by adding **.exe file but again it is sticking with the same error. So I believe there is something wrong with `Program Files (x86)`

Comment: @MagnusBäck you were right. It has been solved the issue. However the path I have to write as Dale mentioned. Thanks to you, Dale and all how tried to help me.

Comment: @Dale yeah the path you provided me that works but just need to add git.exe at the end.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer

The path should be in this format

```
./git-credential-winstore -i /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git/bin
```

Also add to `git.exe` at the end so final path will become

```
./git-credential-winstore -i /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git/bin/git.exe
```

Comment: There is any way to use windows' %ProgramFiles(x86)% instead of hard coding the path? I know inside bash it becomes $PROGRAMFILES(X86) but it expands to "c:\program files" as expected. There is a way to force it expand in nix format?

Answer (score 11):

I was getting a similar error when trying to push or pull my git branch with GitExtensions installed and found [this post](http://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/11/28/git-extensions-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token/) which describes how fix the problem.  The solution was to go to my .gitconfig file at `C:\Users\[user name]\.gitconfig` and change the line:

```
helper = !\\\"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitCredentialWinStore/git-credential-winstore.exe\\\"
```

to:

```
helper = !\"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitCredentialWinStore/git-credential-winstore.exe\"
```

I know my problem was a bit different than the OP's problem, but the error message is the same so I thought I would post my answer here for others who find this post with my problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
user@PC /C
$ ./git-credential-winstore -i C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)\Git\bin\
```